# Type error: Module '"sanity"' has no exported member 'defineConfig'

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel, sanity

I have just finished working on a project using Next.js 13 and Sanity as a headless CMS. Here is the issue I'm experiencing:

When I run

`vercel build`

I get the error that 'sanity' has no exported member 'defineConfig' and this is coming from the sanity.config.ts file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYwu9.png)

I was trying to deploy my next.js project with sanity as a headless CMS.

sanity.config.ts file code :-

```
import { defineConfig } from 'sanity'
import {deskTool} from 'sanity/desk'
import {visionTool} from '@sanity/vision'
import {schemaTypes} from './schemas'

export default defineConfig({
  name: 'default',
  title: 'Portfolio',

  projectId: '0sy14sfv',
  dataset: 'production',

  plugins: [deskTool(), visionTool()],

  schema: {
    types: schemaTypes,
  },
})
```

Comment: can you provide minimal reproducible example? this error is usually related to your sanity package not being updated or worse, the typescript package giving a style error

Comment: i moved my sanity.ts file into a new folder  called lib, the was initially in the root directory. This solved my initial issue. But now I'm getting this "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink 'getExperience.func' -> 'D:\codes\projects\Portfolio1\.vercel\output\functions\api\getPageInfo.func'"

Comment: no don't move it this file needs to be in the root of the project

Comment: It solved the issue I was getting